# Selenium (RSelenium) giving StaleElementReference clicking an element just recently searched

Tags: r, selenium, selenium-webdriver, shiny, rselenium

I'm trying to get some Selenium tests against Shiny app that has some notifications. I have a following function I would call to close all notifications that are there, and the reference to the element is fetched just before the click is called.

```
close_notifications <- function() {
  buttons <- remDr$findElements(using = "xpath", "//[@id='shiny-notification-panel']///div[contains(text(),'×')]")
  close_function <- function(btn) {
    btn$clickElement()
  }
  lapply(buttons, close_function)
}
```

However when there is a notifcation visible in the app and I try to call it, I'll get the following error regarding it.

```
Error: Test failed:
* Summary: StaleElementReference
Detail: An element command failed because the referenced element is no longer attached to the DOM.
class: org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException
```

What might be the reason I'm getting this error, even when the reference is fetched just before trying to click the button? Notification duration itself is quite long so it doesn't disappear in the UI even when I get the StaleElementReference. I'm not sure if Shiny changes something under the hood so that it's not the same DOM element, however, I guess that shouldn't be the case when I'm trying to press the button just after looking it up with the Selenium driver.

Comment: Maybe using `Sys.sleep()` function works?  If it's possible, can you provide the code from the shiny app? thanks!

Comment: There was Sys.sleep() there actually that didn't help unfortunately.